# calling function with parameter in ko dropdownlist binding

Tags: knockout.js, drop-down-menu

I want to bind option values of select tag in knockout , the values
  are comming from a ko viewmodel and the input parameter depends upon
  the outer loop.

it does show populate droupdownlist

it is like this pseudo code

```
 <-- ko for-each {data: travellerlist} -->

    <select data-bind =" foreach: GetYearList($data.passengerType())" >
       <option data-bind="value: key, text: value"></option>    <select>

 <--/ko-->

 function GetYear(passengerType) {

     $.ajax({
         url: baseUrl + 'JavascriptVariables/YearList',
         type: 'get',
         data: { passengerType: passengerType },
         success: function (data) {
             var yearList = [];
             if (data != null ) {
                 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                     yearList.push(key, value);
                 });
                 debugger
                 return yearList;
            }
         },
         error: function (data) {
         }
     }); }
```

Comment: Why don't you use 'options' binding along with 'optionsCaption','optionsText' and 'optionsValue' specified? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: options does not work with function. this the problem i have been facing so i came up with foreach. do you know how to make it work with function?

Comment: Why don't you use a method on the data object? like so: $data.getYearList() and, have the passenger type as a property on the instance already.